# Adding an existing HDD to Windows 11, without losing data

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, multi-boot, windows-11, ubuntu-22.04

I have several hard drives in my system:

- 1TB SSD - Ubuntu 22.04
- 1TB SSD - Windows 11
- 2TB HDD - NTFS data storage

My intent is to have the 2TB HDD be used as shared file storage across both Ubuntu and Windows. The drive is working as expected in Ubuntu (my primary OS) and has a large amount of my personal data.

I installed Windows 11 after Ubuntu was up and running. Switching between OS's works totally fine. This is how my drives appear in Disks on Ubuntu. Note that the 2TB drive is indeed NTFS formatted already:

[image]

Now, I am trying to add access to the 2TB drive from Windows 11. Opening up the Disk Management tool in Win11 looks like this:

[image]

I can see Disk 1, my Ubuntu OS drive. I can see Disk 2, my Win11 C drive. And I can see Disk 0, the 2TB data drive, listed as Unallocated. My goal is to have Disk 2 show up in Windows as a named drive (D:// or similar) while still allowing Ubuntu to access Disk 2 when I have Ubuntu booted.

I have looked for guides on how to resolve the Unallocated Drive in Windows. However, every guide I find for adding an additional drive to Windows 11 starts with

1. Create a New Simple Volume
2. Follow the partitioning/formatting process
3. Assign a drive letter to the new drive

But, I want to avoid partitioning and formatting the drive, because it already has data on it!

I have backed up my data onto an external drive just to be safe, but it seems like there has to be a way to add a hard drive with preexisting data to a Windows system. How else would people recover data from hard drives from old machines, etc?

How do I add an additional hard drive to Windows 11 without reformatting the drive?

EDIT - Here is the fdisk output:

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: ST2000DM008-2UB1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xb5259eee
```

Comment: The shared partition between two different OSes must be with a filesystem both understand. This is very basic knowledge when dual-booting. If said drive "is working as expected in Ubuntu" then it's correctly formatted for Linux (EXT4 or others) or you're using LVM. You need NTFS or exFAT to be able to read/write from both OSes. There are 3rd party software for Windows that enables partial support for EXT4 but it's very flaky and you'll end up regretting using it.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, the 2TB drive is already formatted for NTFS. But I added a screenshot from Ubuntu to validate that for you.

Comment: What is the `Disklabel type` when you run `fdisk -l /dev/sda`? Windows only understands MBR and GPT, but ubuntu can use others. Depending on the type, you may still be able to use 3rd-party software to mount it in windows

Comment: Running `fdisk -l /dev/sda` informs me that `Disklabel type: dos`. Seems like this might be the root cause. Gonna check for a way to change the Disklabel type from DOS to MBR or GPT, but I'm not optimistic about that.

Comment: No, that's not the problem (and MBR is 'msdos' or 'dos'). The problem here is you DIDN'T create a partition then formatted it as NTFS, you simply applied the filesystem to the whole drive, something you can get away with in Linux but CAN'T in Windows, reason why it shows as "unallocated". Now you know what NOT to do in the future.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Thank you for the hint. Although not on point it made me re-check the OP's Disks screenshoot where the problem became obvious (Cf. previous comment). If there was a single partition it would have been identified as `sda1` and, if more, the others would show up sequentially. But instead it's the device itself, `sda`.

Comment: I think you are correct - Windows is expecting the NTFS data to be held within a partition, but I formatted the brand new drive as NTFS without actually creating a partition. Ubuntu has no objection to this, but Windows requires a partition structure to recognize the drive.

@ChanganAuto if you want to write an answer to that effect, I'd happily accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the drive being formatted as NTFS, in Ubuntu, without creating one or more partitions.

The Disks screenshoot shows it as `/dev/sda` which is the device itself. If partitioned with a single partition that would show up as `sda1` and, if with more than one partition, the others would be numbered sequentially.

This is an operation that can be done with relative "impunity" in Linux but renders the data unreadable in Windows, hence the "unallocated" label in Windows Disk Management.

Now the bad news:

There no other way to make it work for Windows as well that isn't creating a new partition table, at least one partition, and format said partition or partitions with a filesystem both OSes can understand, i.e., at the time of this writing, NTFS or exFAT. You need to have backups of any important data already there because the recommended actions will delete everything.

Answer (score 0):

Though the 2 TB drive is marked in Ubuntu *Disks* as NTFS formatted, apparently Windows does not accept that formatting. Yes, Windows and Linux sometimes have their differences. However, **if the drive is formatted NTFS by Windows**, Ubuntu, using *fuse*, should be able to read and write to it.

- First, copy data (it appears to be ~200 GB) from that disk elsewhere.
- Verify that is safely copied.
- From Windows OS, remove all partitions from that drive, then create a single partition. You can use *diskmgmt.msc*, or a third-party tool such as [DiskGenius](https://www.diskgenius.com/) for these tasks.
- From Windows OS, format that partition NTFS.
- Verify that Windows can mount it, and write and read data.
- Verify that Ubuntu can mount it, and write and read data.
- Restore the data to that drive.
- Note that links to data might be lost; for example Linux apps MRU lists will not find last opened files.

**Caveats**

- *If* that drive has Windows system files, and the last Window session was not been *completely* shut down, Ubuntu should open that disk *read-only*. I.E., if Windows was left in Hibernation, or [*Fast Startup*](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup) or [*Fast Boot*](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/enable-or-disable-fast-boot-in-uefi-bios-in-windows) is enabled, and the [file system is marked "dirty"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189766/check-if-a-filesystem-is-marked-dirty).
- Occasionally, I've seen Windows require drive cleanup after Linux writing to the NTFS drive. Usually, issues are quickly resolved without loss of data.

Comment: If you wanna know the reason: https://superuser.com/questions/1829921/adding-an-existing-hdd-to-windows-11-without-losing-data/1829942#comment2885865_1829921 It's this simple. If it was a partition it would show up as `sda1` instead of the device itself, `sda`.